# How can I filtering for Tags(/part of String) in List-mode in OpenXava?

Tags: java, tags, openxava

#### I want to filtering for tags in OpenXava, in List-mode.

---

1. Therefore I have a simple entity called **Tag** ( with `int id, String name and String description`)
2. I have a embedded Entity **Details**, which holds the Tag references and looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class Detail {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
private Tag tag;

public Tag getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return tag.getName();
    
}
```

3. My "main"-entity, called **Target**, represents an Object, which should be able to labeled with Tags.

Therefore have a Collection of Details, to assign Tags to Targets, which can't be represented in List-mode

```
@Tab(name="TargetTab", editors="List", properties="id, tags, manufacturer.name, owner.name, protocolID, idCreationDate, simDBID, remark, changeDate, photo, xphoto")
@Entity
public class Target implements Serializable {

...

@ElemtentCollection
@ListProperties("tag.number, tag.name, tag.description")
@Embedded
Collection<Detail> details;

    public Collection<Detail> getDetails() { 
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Collection<Detail> details) { 
        this.details = details;
        tags = details.toString().substring(1, details.toString().length() - 1);
    }

...
```

To represent Tags in List-mode, I created a String, which is filled with the name of the Tags

```
...
@ReadOnly
String tags;

...
```

This creates a cloumn "Tags" in List-mode, which is representet by a String like: "a,b,c,d"

For filtering in List-mode, OpenXava has by default an input box, in which you can type a String like: "a,b" , to get all entries with the tags "a" and "b"

But if I enter "a,c", no results will be shown, even though there are entries with the tags "a,b,c,d"

**My goal/problem:**

I want a flexible filter, in which I can type something like: "a,c" and get all entries, that contain the tags "a" and "c"

I tried out to realize it by a `"TagFilter.class"` with `"baseCondition="${tags} = ?"` in the Target entity, with no usable result

Answer (score 0):

The tags property in Target has no relation with the tag values of details collection. The tags property in Target is just a new column in your table.

You have to options:

1. Define tags property using @Formula
2. Update the tags property each time a detail is added/removed (you can use JPA callback methods for that)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solutions, but my problem is not, how to fill the property with values.

Actually I want, to edit the behavior of the search filter, in List-mode of my Tag-string. Currently I only can filter for whole/concatenated Strings.

Comment: If tags is an string property should be able of filter by 'contains', indeed that is the default comparator. About to customize the filtering parameters there is an interfaz called IFilter and an property in the @Tab called filter for that purpose.